# How to configure routes in asp.net mvc with Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am working on asp.net mvc 3. I have three areas in my project like,

```
MyProject/Areas/Blogs
MyProject/Areas/Forums
MyProject/Areas/Groups
```

Among these three, blogs view is startup view. for that i have set the globla.ascx as

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Blog", action = "Blog", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

and in BlogAreaRegistration.cs,

```
context.MapRoute(
                "Blogarea_Default",
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Blog", action = "Blog", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

and in ForumAreaRegistration.cs,

```
context.MapRoute(
                null,
                "Forums/{action}/{id}",
                new {controller="Forums", action = "Forum", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

and in GroupsAreaRegisration.cs,

```
   context.MapRoute(
        "Groups_default",
        "Groups/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Groups", action = "Group", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Here Forum and Blog are work as i desire but the Group does not work it always shows **404 Resource not found page** so please guide me if i did any mistake in the process.

Answer (score 2):

Try change

```
 context.MapRoute(
        "Groups_default",
        "Groups/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Groups", action = "Group", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

for:

```
 context.MapRoute(
        "Groups_default",
        "Groups/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Groups", action = "Group", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Comment: @Rogulski: I did the above mentioned changes but i didnt get desired output. It again shows same 404 error

Comment: How looks your url which generate `404` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove either `Groups/` or `{controller}/` from your `GroupsAreaRegisration.cs` code block - then it should work. I'd remove `{controller}/`, so the code will be:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Groups_default",
    "Groups/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Groups", action = "Group", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Also in `BlogAreaRegistration.cs` I'd replace `{controller}` with `Blog`, as you might get quite unexpected results otherwise. The complete code here will be

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Blogarea_Default",
    "Blog/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Blog", action = "Blog", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```